# How to calculate the double integral of the integral area related to the parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I know that the `Integrate` function of MMA can compute double integrals.

```
Integrate[x*y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]
```

Now I want to use MMA to calculate the result of this integral:

$$\iint_{x+y<=z}{\mathrm{e} ^{-\frac{x^2}{2} }\mathrm{e} ^{-\frac{y^2}{2} }}\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$

The integral area of this double integral is related to the parameter `z`, so the result of this double integral is related to the parameter `z`. I know that the calculation of the above double integral according to the convolution formula is as follows:

```
    Integrate[
 Integrate[
  E^(-(x^2/2)) (E^(-((z - x)^2/
     2))), {x, -∞, +∞}], {z, -∞, z}]
    (*π (erf(z/2)+1)*)
```

But I can't get results when I execute his equivalent code:

```
    reg = ImplicitRegion[x + y <= z, {x, y}];
Integrate[E^(-(x^2/2)) E^(-(y^2/2)), {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

I want to know how to use `Mathematica` to calculate this type of double integral.

In addition, I don't want to use extra mathematical skills to calculate this kind of double integral.

Comment: It’s an infinite region on which the integral diverges, no?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. I've changed to a convergent integrand.

Comment: This suggests there's a stumbling block (taking `z = 1`): `Integrate[E^(-(x^2/2)) E^(-(y^2/2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, 1 - x}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `ImplicitRegion` with a symbolic `z` that isn't part of the coordinate list  - it won't work for some reason and Wolfram should probably document this in the *Possible Issues* section in the help. Consider this incorrect example too:

```
disk = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y}]
Area[disk]
(* returns: 0 *)
```

Instead, use an equivalent explicit region such as `HalfPlane[{{z, 0}, {0, z}}, {-1, -1}];`:

```
reg2 = HalfPlane[{{z, 0}, {0, z}}, {-1, -1}];
Integrate[Exp[-x^2/2] Exp[-y^2/2], {x, y} ∈ reg2]

(* result: ConditionalExpression[π (1 + Erf[z/2]), (z | z) ∈ Reals] *)
```

Comment: Wow, `ImplicitRegion` is so buggy! By the way, using your first example, I am getting the correct answer imposing assumptions `disk = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y}]; Assuming[r>0,Area[disk]]`. I have MA12.1

Comment: @yarchik interesting - I tried assumptions for z on x+y<=z but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Yes, it does not help in this case...